# Is the directives meta-data no longer required in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm currently following along with 'the complete guide to angular 2' video lessons, and every time he needs to import a component, he also makes sure to add it to the directives like this: 
`

```
@Component({
 selector: 'rb-recipe-list',
 templateUrl: './recipe-list.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./recipe-list.component.css'],
 directives: [RecipeItemComponent]
})
```

`

But it works for me, even if i dont have the directives line. I'm not even sure the point of it, if I already imported the component in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct, it is superfluous, at least in the current (4.4.6) version.

See the current [meta-data descriptor of @Component](https://angular.io/api/core/Component):

```
@Component({ 
  changeDetection?: ChangeDetectionStrategy
  viewProviders?: Provider[]
  moduleId?: string
  templateUrl?: string
  template?: string
  styleUrls?: string[]
  styles?: string[]
  animations?: any[]
  encapsulation?: ViewEncapsulation
  interpolation?: [string, string]
  entryComponents?: Array<Type<any>|any[]>
  preserveWhitespaces?: boolean
  // inherited from core/Directive
  selector?: string
  inputs?: string[]
  outputs?: string[]
  host?: {[key: string]: string}
  providers?: Provider[]
  exportAs?: string
  queries?: {[key: string]: any}
})
```

...and the lack thereof of `directives: []`.

Perhaps worth noting, from the same documentation linked above:

> [...] Angular components are a subset of directives.

[Furthermore](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive):

> A directive must belong to an NgModule in order for it to be usable by another directive, component, or application. To specify that a directive is a member of an NgModule, you should list it in the declarations field of that NgModule.

So, Directives are declared in an NgModule and available to all Components declared within that module, or lazy-loaded child modules.

Comment: Awesome! I thought I was missing something important haha